# Angular 7 app not working in IE11 with SCRIPT5007: Object expected error

Tags: angular

I have a project in Angular 7 which is working fine across all browsers except for IE11 where the login screen occasional loads and occasionally just stays blank with an error in the debugger. It's about 50/50 whether it loads or not but in same cases seems to go to 100% not loading.

The error that's showing in the console is:

**SCRIPT5007: Object expected

zone.js (240,1)**

The relevant code in the zone.js file reads:

```
try {
    task = this._zoneDelegate.scheduleTask(this, task);
}
catch (err) {
    // should set task's state to unknown when scheduleTask throw error
    // because the err may from reschedule, so the fromState maybe notScheduled
    task._transitionTo(unknown, scheduling, notScheduled);
    // TODO: @JiaLiPassion, should we check the result from handleError?
    this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, err);
    throw err;
}
```

Where line 240 is the "throw err" line.

The app has been working fine in IE11 until very recently, we have uncommented all the imports in the polyfills.js file.

Any help or insight would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try loading all of the polyfills from the `core-js` folder in your vendors. The imports listed in `polyfills.ts` is *incomplete* and only shows what is needed to run the Angular core.

Comment: Thanks cgTag, I'm not quite following though. Where do I find the polyfills that I would need to load?

Comment: look in `/node_modules/core-js`. You'll see that the `polyfills.ts` only imports some of them. There are ES6 and ES7 polyfills there. I don't know if this will fix your issue, but I always try adding more when I run into IE issues and sometimes it fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and trying different solutions we have eventually solved this problem. It was caused by a small piece of third party script from Hotjar that had been included on the index.html file of the app. Removing the code, effectively removing Hotjar, has fixed this issue with IE11.